# How to determine whether undirected graph can be colored red or black so that there are no two consecutive reds or blacks

Tags: algorithm, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search, graph-traversal

This is a question asked in the interview.

Interviewer wanted me to argue that my solution is correct and it runs in `O(|V| + |E|)`

I simply froze.

More specifically, as in why this is not straightforward, consider following subquestions:

1. Under what circumstances, the answer will be no, we cannot.
2. What is preferred BFS or DFS, why?
3. Isn't having undirected graph make it difficult? because I can travel back and forth, so if there is a cycle of even nodes, it seems we cannot really do so, IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A graph that has this property is called a [bipartite graph](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph) and there are a couple of nice algorithms you can use to test if a graph is bipartite.

A key theorem about bipartite graphs is that a graph is bipartite if and only if it contains no cycles of odd length. This theorem is really helpful because it means that if you do ever end up revisiting a node you’ve seen, you can determine whether it matters at all to you. If that closes an odd-length cycle, you know for a fact that the graph isn’t bipartite and you’re done. Otherwise, if it closes an even-length cycle, you can ignore it and move on.

Based on that, you can check if a graph is bipartite by doing either a DFS or a BFS of the graph, with a few small modifications. First, keep track of the depth that you’re at in the search. Mark all nodes at even levels red and all nodes at odd levels black. As you do the search, if you assign a node a color and notice that one of its neighbors has already been given the same color, then you have an odd-length cycle and you can report that no coloring exists (do you see why?). If this never happens, then you’ve colored each node either red or black with no two adjacenf nodes of the same color, and you’re done!

Since this adds a constant amount of work per node to the BFS or DFS, the runtime ends up being linear in the size of the graph. You can pick whichever search algorithm you’d like; the tradeoff in the selection depends on other factors like memory usage, etc.

For what it’s worth, bipartite graphs are a pretty famous and useful class of graphs, and it might be worth reading up on them in the future. They have a ton of cool properties and nifty applications!